# bootstrap-table / How to add filter-control in table configuration

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-table

I'm trying to make a filter per column in **Bootstrap-table**.

I've seen a lot of sites that use the HTML **data-filter-control** tag to do this, **but I want to do it in the javascript side**; preferably on the table configuration attributes.

This is an HTML **data-filter-control** tag example:

```
  <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
            <th data-field="prenom" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Prénom</th>
            <th data-field="date" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Date</th>
            <th data-field="examen" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Examen</th>
            <th data-field="note" data-sortable="true">Note</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function () {
  $('#table').bootstrapTable({
    filterControl: true,
    disableUnusedSelectOptions: true,

    columns: [
      {
        field: "first_column",
        title: "First Column",
        filterControl: 'input',
        filterControlPlaceholder: "holder",
        filterStrictSearch: false
      },{
        field:  "second_column",
        title: "Second Column",
        filterControl: 'select',
        filterStrictSearch: false,
      },
    ]

  });
});
```