# Bootstrap-Table add a default filter on table create

Tags: bootstrap-table

My filter for the column is working, what I want to do now is make a default filter, that will applied on table creation.

```
<table id="testTable"
 data-side-pagination="server"> 
            <thead>

                    <tr>
                        <th class="question" data-field="UserFullName" data-sortable="false" data-filter-control="select">Name: </th>
                        <th class="question" data-field="UserJobTitle" data-sortable="false" data-filter-control="select" data-filter-data="var:userJobTitles">JobTitle: </th>
                    </tr>        

            </thead>

<script>
    var userJobTitles = {
            Admin: 'Admin',
            IT: 'IT',
            General : 'General',
            Security : 'Security',
            CEO : 'CEO',
    };
</script>
```

In this example, I want to make IT Jobtitle a default job title. 
This seems to be close to the solution [bootstrap-table / How to add filter-control in table configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46851474/bootstrap-table-how-to-add-filter-control-in-table-configuration) , the issue is that i dont want to do it on the javascript side.

Answer (score 1):

I think this feature is available out of the box in Bootstrap Table. Please see: [filterDefault column option documentation](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/extensions/filter-control/#filterdefault)

There is no need to write JavaScript for that, you could just use `data-filter-default` attribute on the `<th>` element corresponding to the column which you want to filter. So in your case it would be:

```
<th class="question" 
    data-field="UserJobTitle" 
    data-sortable="false" 
    data-filter-control="select" 
    data-filter-data="var:userJobTitles" 
    data-filter-default="IT">JobTitle: </th>
```

**Important:** It is necessary to use the "key" of your `data-filter-data` (see: [filterData column option documentation](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/extensions/filter-control/#filterdata)).

Hopefully this helps :).